Drizzle sql operator doesn't match expect.anything() in vitest
This test
 expect(dbMock.where).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  gte(messageFeed.timestamp, expect.anything())
 );

fails for this:
 .where(
  gte(messageFeed.timestamp, sql`now() - interval '1 day'`)
 )

but works fine for:
 .where(
  gte(messageFeed.timestamp, new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
 )

I am putting different values in the second parameter of gte and the test is positive, but if I put in a sql`` drizzle operator - it fails.
